# Webview load my html page that containing webservices but these are not shown

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-studio, webview

First of all excuse my English

I'm making an android application containing fragments and these in turn show a webview . The webview loads a html page and this called a webservices . Webservices are not being charged by the application but they work correctly in the html.

(I'm using a host)
(Webservices are Json)

[Here is running in webnavigator perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC8ii.jpg)

[Here is running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVtTm.jpg)

This is the Html (Materialize Framework)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.css"></script>
<!---------------------------------------------------  TABLA SUB 14 A ----------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="card-panel teal darken">
 <span>Tabla Sub 14A</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
   <table  class='bordered hoverable highlight'>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <td>Equipo</td>
      <td>Pj</td>
      <td>Pg</td>
      <td>Pe</td>
      <td>Pp</td>
      <td>Pts</td>
      <td>Gf</td>
      <td>Ge</td>
      <td>Dif</td>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="id01">
    </tbody>
   </table>
   
   
  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>



<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://afezdatosapk.esy.es/JsonSub14A.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<tbody>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        arr[i].equipo +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].pj +
        "</td><td>" +
  arr[i].pg +
        "</td><td>" +
  arr[i].pe +
        "</td><td>" +
  arr[i].pp +
        "</td><td>" +
  arr[i].pts +
        "</td><td>" +
  arr[i].gf +
        "</td><td>" +
  arr[i].ge +
        "</td><td>" +
  arr[i].dif +
        "</td><td>";
    }
    out += "</tbody>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```

Android java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tablas, container, false);


    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.tablasweb);
    webView.loadUrl("http://afezdatosapk.esy.es/TablaSub14.html");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public boolean shouldoOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            return false;
        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

Android XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rwa.afezproject.Tablas">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tablasweb">

</WebView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Also try debugging webview in chrome to check any error in console.